# Someone explain this please... (C# Lambda expression)

Tags: c#

What's the difference between

```
Func<string,int> returnLength;
returnLength = (string text) => { return text.Length; };
Console.WriteLine (returnLength("Hello"));
```

and simply

```
  string str = "Hello";
  Console.WriteLine (str.Length);
```

Any advantages using one of those?

Comment: This like asking what is the difference between `x++` and `x=Add(x,1)`. Both yield the same results. There isn't enough information given in the above post to really make call, other than go for the simplest one that works.

Comment: The short answer is no difference!
Since you've commented here saying it's just an example then maybe you should rephrase your question? Do you want to get a better understanding of what Lambdas are and where you would use them?

Comment: +1 jalexiou, hahaha funny question. But technically speaking : 'what's the difference between ... and simple': if executing method 1 defines and initializes an extra concrete type b) costs at least 4 more IL opcodes then method 2 (both define a string resource Hello so no difference)     'Any advantages using one of those?'    mmm this one ... ah this one gets me sorry:)

Comment: I mean no harm, +1 to you in apology for being disrespectful above, I am sorry. I know you have a reason to ask this, but it's really not clear and I just read it and pictured irrelevant situation. I'm sorry again. Btw: maybe if you describe a potential scenario you like to use the above code many good suggestions may come. Or do you just want to learn lambadas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question isn't really about when to use lambda expressions so much as when to use delegates in general. The answer is that you use delegates as a way of encapsulating behaviour and passing it around.

Examples of where that's useful:

- Event handlers (the most common example being a user interface event such as a button click)
- Async operation callbacks ("run this code when you've finished downloading the web page")
- LINQ operations ("perform filtering using this predicate")
- Starting new threads ("when the thread has been created, run this code in it")

All of these *could* be done with interfaces instead; delegates are similar to single-method interfaces in many ways. However, delegates are often a neater solution, partly because you can create a delegate more flexibly than implementing an interface, using an individual method or expressing the logic inline with an anonymous method or lambda expression.

Comment: @yonan2236: That explains it - I often use simple examples just to demonstrate *syntax*, but those examples are often separate from where you'd *really* use it.

Answer (score 2):

The lambda gives you a function that you can now pass to other functions, instead of hardcoding the access to the `Length` member.

Comment: Yes, but why *wouldn't* you want to hardcode accessing the Length member? The lambda only operates on strings... it's not exactly versatile to begin with.

Comment: @Mark, I'm sure the OP is using just a trivial example. Don't focus on the specific code but rather the concept.

Comment: @Mark: Because maybe you want a function that converts the string to an integer. Or one that gives the number of times a certain substring appears in it. Think of Python's `list.sort()` 's `key` argument. http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types

Comment: @Ignacio: But he named it `returnLength`. If it did anything else,... if it were non-trivial it might make sense, but then you'd probably want to use an actual function, not a lambda.

Comment: @Mark: Sure. But that's not what he's asking.

Comment: Well it's hard to say without a better example. For the example he's given a flat "no" seems appropriate. I can't think of a situation where it *is* appropriate to use a lambda unless you've already got a function that takes one, or you're defining a function that takes one. But to use it in a chunk of procedural code..doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 2):

Technically, both options work. However, you might choose one for various reasons. However, this one seems the most important to me:

**Simplicity, readability, maintainability** - some lambda expressions, especially LINQ ones, are shorter and more maintainable than their non-lambda equivalents.

**In this case, it seems that the lambda is actually using more space.** Thus, personally, I would prefer the second option. However, in my other cases, lambdas are a better choice.

In terms of performance: as far as I know, lambdas are a little slower. Of course, in this situation, that difference is negligible.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the first can simply be rewritten as

```
Func<string, int> returnLength = text => text.Length;
```

The usefulness of the first is that it can be used where a delegate is needed, most commonly when using LINQ, as you would typically provide a lambda when using many of the extension methods that make LINQ function.

In other situations, you may define methods that accept `Func<>` or `Action<>` parameters that encapsulate logic or behavior. The caller is free to specify what that particular logic is, all the callee is concerned with is that *some* sort of logic be provided.

Comment: Out of curiosity, could you use `var` in place of `Func<string,int>`? Wait... no you couldn't... what if you prefixed `text` with `string`?

Comment: @Mark - Not a fan of `var` unless I really need it. But in this case, simply using `var` is an error unless you provide a cast, such as `var returnLength = (Func<string, int>)(text => text.Length);` As you can see, there is nothing to be gained in this case.

Comment: I just can't really imagine a scenario where it will be more advantageous to use delegates and lambda expression.

Comment: @yonan, don't force them. In your example in the question, it's *not* more useful. But as you use the language more and more, you will use lambdas more and more unless you intentionally steer clear of the niceties of C# 3+.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something, the latter looks much clearer, and simpler. Why would you complicate things by using lambdas?

Answer (score 0):

The second is more advantageous because it produces the same result with less code.  It's more understandable and more maintainable.  Unless you have a need for the lambda that you have not noted, I don't see any reason to go with the more complicated version.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have that uses the `Func` method seems to be just a proof-of-concept, or a demonstration of what lambda expressions and functions are; you would not use lamdas in such a simple case of finding the length of a string.
Lamda expressions and functions do a LOT MORE than just displaying a string's length.

The second one is the quick, relatively optimized method of retrieving a string's length.

There's more than one way to Rome, yes, but why go round the equator when you can just take a left turn right here?